# any .net unit test framework supports for nested sections within a function based fixture like C++ Catch framework

Tags: c#, c++, try-catch, unit-testing

I am using C++ unit test framwork named Catch
https://github.com/philsquared/Catch

And I think its approach is very easy to pick up and organize tests:

- Support for nested sections within a function based fixture

Example:

```
Scenarios("abc....")
{
    Given("xyz")
    { 
        When("uvt..")
        { 
            Then("erew")
            {
            }
        }

        And_When("ssd")
        {
            Then("324")
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The good thing about this structure is that it is easy to reuse setup and support new variations of the scenarios (green path vs not so green path)

So I just wonder any one have seen thing like this with other unit test framework in C#.
Thanks.

Answer my own question:
I found NJasmine: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NJasmine
Which gives me what I want.